# How to integrate Admob with windows phone in cocos2d-x 2.2.1

Tags: windows-phone-8, admob, cocos2d-x

Want to Integrate Admob with cocos2d-x 2.2.1 in windows phone, there no direct connection to implement that. How i can do this ? 
 engine version-
2.2.1

I am new in cocos2d-x, now i am trying to add Admob with windows phone. Currently my project working fine with windows but there is next task to implement admob. So please provide me way for that.

thank you

Comment: There is crash in admob sdk so I use vserve on place of admob.